# Customizing search widget with searchform.php does not work

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've defined a widget called ‘Main Sidebar’ in the functions.php.
I have added a search form for the ‘Main Sidebar’ in WordPress UI appearance > widget . All objects inside the widget are displayed correctly as a sidebar with the command dynamic_sidebar(‘main_sidebar’) in single.php.
I want to customize search form inside the widget with searchform.php but it is just ignored.

What is the procedure to customize search form inside a widget?

single.php:

```
<aside id="sidebar">

        <?php dynamic_sidebar('main_sidebar'); ?>

      </aside>
```

searchform.php:

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">

    <input type="search"  name="s" placeholder="Search Here..." value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>">

    <input type="submit" id="search-btn" value="">

</form>
```

functions.php

```
function fcc_widgets(){
    register_sidebar([
        'name' => 'Main Sidebar',
        'id' => 'main_sidebar',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
         
    ]);
     
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'fcc_widgets');
```

Comment: actually the connection between your files is not clear, Also it seems something is missing.